# C# SqlConnection ConnectionString

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection-string

Could someone please help me in finding the correct SQL Connection String to connect to my database in C#. The database I wish to connect to is shown in the following screenshot from SQL Management Studio

[image]

Comment: Have you tried http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Try here:
[SQL Server connection strings](http://www.sqlstrings.com/SQL-Server-connection-strings.htm)

Comment: These are just your instances of SQL Server, you'll need to know the actual database names/servers/credentials in order to build a connection string.

Comment: Make sure that you have internet connection that allows you to connect to port 1433. Ones I was working from Starbucks and I couldn't connect to the sql server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store your connection strings in you web.config or app.config file. I have placed an example string in a snippett here:

```
<configure>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="YOURDESIREDCONNECTIONSTRINGNAME" connectionString="Data Source=IPADDRESSorURL;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;User ID=YOURUSERNAME;Password=YOURPASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configure>
```

In your scenario, you are using SQL Express so use the following:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
```

As far as you have described the question, this is the best answer I can give at the moment. I hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The most helpful answer, in light of the `C#` tag, on the question.

Answer (score 2):

The instance of SQL Server that you have highlighted is SQL Server Express which is either connected to using:

```
.\sqlexpress
```

or

```
SERVERNAME\sqlexpress
```

You can try:

```
Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=YOURDATABASENAME;User Id=YOURSQLUSERNAME;Password=YOURSQLUSERPASSWORD;
```

or

```
Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=YOURDATABASENAME;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

As others have said take a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for further reference on sql server connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

This site contains everything you need: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/.
In your case server addres is `.\sqlexpress` or `serverName\sqlexpress`.